# Are there any space capable countries without ITAR laws?

Tags: law, international-politics, itar

In the US, the draconian ITAR laws prevent an open source space program from being founded, and make it incredibly difficult to found any aerospace company in general.  Are there any countries that have either a government run space program or private space companies that do not have ITAR laws or equivalents?

Comment: Anti-proliferation treaties requires some degree of restriction

Comment: @JCRM anti-nuclear-weapons proliferation, do you mean? I am pretty sure there's some countries that are not signatories to that.

Comment: absolutely @ikrase, those would be good places to look.

Comment: North Korea perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't want to work with Iran or North Korea, other space capable countries will have SOME form of export controls in place. ITAR is one aspect of the U.S. export control regime. India is probably your best bet if you wanted to find a jurisdiction with a relatively relaxed regulatory framework and the ability to domestically produce components (thus avoiding the need to import parts from Western countries, which just puts you at the mercy of export controls anyway). But even then, you're likely going to need rad-hardened and other specialized components that are hard to get domestically in India.